# How to create a negative NumberPicker

Tags: android, numberpicker

Does anyone know of an easy way to allow negative numbers with Android's default numberpicker?  I understand that it's the InputFilter that disallows this, but is there any easy way to override without rewriting the whole widget?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11303100/numberpicker-with-negative-and-possitive-values

Answer (score 15):

A more generic and elegant solution is to use [NumberPicker.Formatter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.Formatter.html) and use only positive numbers in the NumberPicker.

Example if I want to select a number in [-50, 50]:

```
final int minValue = -50
final int maxValue = 50
NumberPicker numberPicker = new NumberPicker(myActivity);
numberPicker.setMinValue(0);
numberPicker.setMaxValue(maxValue - minValue);
numberPicker.setValue(myCurrentValue - minValue);
numberPicker.setFormatter(new NumberPicker.Formatter() {
    @Override
    public String format(int index) {
        return Integer.toString(index + minValue);
    }
});
```

then to get back the selected value:

```
int myNewValue = numberPicker.getValue() + minValue
```

Comment: user3343995 is correct, it should be "return Integer.toString(index + minValue);" in the format() method override.

Answer (score 5):

Use:

```
String[] nums {"-1","-2","-3","-4"};
numberpicker.setDisplayedValues(nums);
```

or

```
String[] nums = new String[4];
for(int i=0; i<nums.length; i++)
nums[i] = "-" + Integer.toString(i);
numberpicker.setDisplayedValues(nums);
```

Either of those will let you use any set of Strings for your NumberPicker. What you are doing is you are specifying a set of strings which you the pass to the NumberPicker. Then it will display your values instead of the default ones.

Answer (score 1):

Using `.setFormatter()` doesn't allow entry of negative numbers. With `.setDisplayedValues()` the keyboard is shown textual instead of numeric.
So here is the class `SignedNumberPicker`:

```
class SignedNumberPicker extends android.widget.NumberPicker {
  int nToAdd=0,mMaxValue=0,mMinValue=0;
  EditText tv;
  private void init() {
    super.setFormatter(new Formatter() {
      @Override
      public String format(int i) {
        int r=i-nToAdd;
        return String.valueOf(r);
      }
    });
    tv.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED);
    tv.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new InputTextFilter()});
    tv.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
      @Override
      public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
        if (b) {
          tv.selectAll();
        } else {
          String str = String.valueOf(((EditText) view).getText());
          if (TextUtils.isEmpty(str.replace("-",""))) {
            tv.setText(String.valueOf(getRealValue()));
          } else {
            textToValue();
          }
          InputMethodManager keyboard = (InputMethodManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context
              .INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
          if (keyboard != null) {
            keyboard.hideSoftInputFromWindow(tv.getWindowToken(),0);
          }
          tv.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
        }
        if (mOnTextFocusChangedListener!=null) {
          mOnTextFocusChangedListener.onTextFocusChanged(b);
        }
      }
    });
  }
  void textToValue() {
    try {
      setValue(Integer.valueOf(tv.getText().toString()));
    } catch (Exception e) {}
  }
  OnTextFocusChangedListener mOnTextFocusChangedListener =null;
  public interface OnTextFocusChangedListener {
    void onTextFocusChanged(boolean textViewHasFocus);
  }
  public void setOnTextFocusChangedListener(OnTextFocusChangedListener l) {
    mOnTextFocusChangedListener =l;
  }
  public SignedNumberPicker(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
  }
  public SignedNumberPicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
  }
  @Override
  public void addView(View child) {
    super.addView(child);
    init(child);
  }
  @Override
  public void addView(View child, int index, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
    super.addView(child, index, params);
    init(child);
  }
  @Override
  public void addView(View child, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
    super.addView(child, params);
    init(child);
  }
  private void init(View view) {
    if(view instanceof EditText){
      tv=((EditText) view);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void setMinValue(int minValue) {
    if (minValue<0) {
      nToAdd=-minValue;
      super.setMaxValue(super.getMaxValue()+nToAdd);
    }
    mMinValue=minValue;
    super.setMinValue(minValue+nToAdd);
  }

  @Override
  public void setMaxValue(int maxValue) {
    if (maxValue+nToAdd<0) {
      nToAdd=-maxValue;
    }
    mMaxValue=maxValue;
    super.setMaxValue(maxValue+nToAdd);
  }

  @Override
  public void setValue(int value) {
    super.setValue(value+nToAdd);
  }
  public int getRealValue() {
    if (tv.hasFocus()) textToValue();
    return super.getValue()-nToAdd;
  }
  private NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener mOnValueChangedListener=null;
  @Override
  public void setOnValueChangedListener(OnValueChangeListener onValueChangedListener) {
    mOnValueChangedListener=onValueChangedListener;
    super.setOnValueChangedListener(new OnValueChangeListener() {
      @Override
      public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
        mOnValueChangedListener.onValueChange(picker,oldVal-nToAdd,newVal-nToAdd);
      }
    });
  }

  //copied from NumberPicker source & modified
  //https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/NumberPicker.java
  class InputTextFilter extends NumberKeyListener {

    // XXX This doesn't allow for range limits when controlled by a
    // soft input method!
    public int getInputType() {
      return InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT;
    }

    @Override
    protected char[] getAcceptedChars() {
      return DIGIT_CHARACTERS;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(
        CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
      // We don't know what the output will be, so always cancel any
      // pending set selection command.
      /*if (mSetSelectionCommand != null) {
        mSetSelectionCommand.cancel();
      }*/
      //and we will ignore this

      CharSequence filtered = super.filter(source, start, end, dest, dstart, dend);
      if (filtered == null) {
        filtered = source.subSequence(start, end);
      }

      String result = String.valueOf(dest.subSequence(0, dstart)) + filtered
          + dest.subSequence(dend, dest.length());

      if ("".equals(result)) {
        return result;
      }
      int val = getSelectedPos(result);

    /*
     * Ensure the user can't type in a value greater than the max
     * allowed. We have to allow less than min as the user might
     * want to delete some numbers and then type a new number.
     * And prevent multiple-"0" that exceeds the length of upper
     * bound number.
     */
      if (val > mMaxValue || (result.length() > String.valueOf(mMaxValue).length() && result
          .length()>String.valueOf(mMinValue).length()) || (val<0 && val<mMinValue)) {
        return "";
      } else {
        return filtered;
      }
    }
    private int getSelectedPos(String value) {
      try {
        return Integer.parseInt(value);
      } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        // Ignore as if it's not a number we don't care
      }
      return mMinValue;
    }
    private final char[] DIGIT_CHARACTERS = new char[] {
        //THE MINUS SIGN
        '-',
        // Latin digits are the common case
        '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
        // Arabic-Indic
        '\u0660', '\u0661', '\u0662', '\u0663', '\u0664', '\u0665', '\u0666', '\u0667', '\u0668'
        , '\u0669',
        // Extended Arabic-Indic
        '\u06f0', '\u06f1', '\u06f2', '\u06f3', '\u06f4', '\u06f5', '\u06f6', '\u06f7', '\u06f8'
        , '\u06f9',
        // Hindi and Marathi (Devanagari script)
        '\u0966', '\u0967', '\u0968', '\u0969', '\u096a', '\u096b', '\u096c', '\u096d', '\u096e'
        , '\u096f',
        // Bengali
        '\u09e6', '\u09e7', '\u09e8', '\u09e9', '\u09ea', '\u09eb', '\u09ec', '\u09ed', '\u09ee'
        , '\u09ef',
        // Kannada
        '\u0ce6', '\u0ce7', '\u0ce8', '\u0ce9', '\u0cea', '\u0ceb', '\u0cec', '\u0ced', '\u0cee'
        , '\u0cef'
    };
  }
}
```

Use it like "normal" NumberPicker, but feel free to use negative numbers. Instead of `getValue()`, use `getRealValue()`, beacuse `getValue()` is used internally by NumberPicker (!?).
I also added `setOnTextFocusChangedListener()` method, which might be convenient for disabling OK button etc.

Update:
If you want to prevent user from entering the same value, you can disable OK button as long as keyboard is shown, and listen to value change:

```
dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(false);
numberPicker.setOnTextFocusChangedListener(new SignedNumberPicker.OnTextFocusChangedListener() {
  @Override
  public void onTextFocusChanged(boolean textViewHasFocus) {
    if (textViewHasFocus) {
      dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(false);
    } else {
      dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(numberPicker.getRealValue()!=currentValue);
    }
  }
});
numberPicker.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
  @Override
  public void onValueChange(android.widget.NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
    dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(newVal!=currentValue);
  }
});
```

Comment: @ge0rg That's true. NumberPicker doesn't get updated untill you press `Done` on the keyboard. But that's why I added OnTextFocusChangedListener, to disable OK button while keyboard is shown - see the updated answer.

Comment: I've solved the problem by moving the textedit->setValue() logic into its own function and calling it from `getRealValue()` if `tv.hasFocus()`. You might want to change your solution accordingly. Also had to remove `tv.setVisibility(GONE)`. Alternatively I can provide the final code as a new answer here.

Comment: Good idea, @ge0rg. I updated the answer. Why did you have to remove `tv.setVisibility(GONE)` (`INVISBLE`)? Without `tv.setVisibility(INVISIBLE)`, `OnTextFocusChangedListener` doesn't work, because `tv` receives focus again. I also added hide keyboard code, because touching the text input can lead to it become invisible, with keyboard still shown. For my solution, I need to prevent user from entering the same value, so I stick to disabling OK button, like in the second piece of code.

Comment: I had to do `tv.setVisibility(INVISIBLE)` because on Android 4.1, the EditText is also the actual view showing the selected number, so hiding it made the picker display emptyness in the middle. Not sure when or what exactly changed, but removing it made it work mostly.

Comment: I don't know. I tried it in emulator with 4.1 (API 16, which is min. API for my project), and it works fine.

Answer (score -2):

[Here](http://www.quietlycoding.com/?p=5) is the example which you are looking for.

```
private static final int DEFAULT_MAX = 200;
private static final int DEFAULT_MIN = 0;// change this acc to your requirement
```

Comment: I understand that this is a feasible solution, but I was asking specifically if it was possible to override the stock android widget, as I feel it would help to keep my app future proof when android decides to adjust the look and feel of the OS again.