# Android numberpicker negative values

Tags: android, numberpicker

I have A array that have negative and positive values, but when I start the app I only can see the minimum value in the picker.

```
int min = -25;
int max = 100;
int jumpBy = 5;

        String [] refl_Str = new String[((max-min)/jumpBy)+1];


        for (int i = 0; i < refl_Str.length; i++) 
        {
            refl_Str[i] = Integer.toString(min+(i*jumpBy));


        }

        np.setDisplayedValues(refl_Str);
```

When I add:

```
np.setMaxValue(100);
np.setMinValue(-25);
```

I get error on negative values in the numberpicker.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android NumberPicker - Negative Numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14357520/android-numberpicker-negative-numbers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use following code to do that:

```
final int minValue = -25
final int maxValue = 100
NumberPicker numberPicker = new NumberPicker(myActivity);
numberPicker.setMinValue(0);
numberPicker.setMaxValue(maxValue - minValue);
numberPicker.setValue(myCurrentValue - minValue);
numberPicker.setFormatter(new NumberPicker.Formatter() {
    @Override
    public String format(int index) {
        return Integer.toString(index - minValue);
    }
});
```

then to get back the selected value:

```
int myNewValue = numberPicker.getValue() + minValue
```

Comment: What about jumping by 5?

Comment: this is just sample that want to say, you must setMinValue to `0` and setMaxValue to `maxValue - minValue`, other thing you can handled like your code

Comment: On Nexus5 and Lollipop, this does not work. Just I move the selector wheel, numbers jumps of -minvalue.

Comment: As @ARLabs mentioned, now the NumberPicker parses the current value as text when scrolling and sets the value to the parsed value, not the `myCurrentValue - minValue` type of value that we want.