# Range NumberPicker

Tags: android, android-number-picker

I saw [Numberpicker](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi_l7_Fj_fVAhWFXRoKHemVBP4QFggoMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Freference%2Fandroid%2Fwidget%2FNumberPicker.html&usg=AFQjCNF3vT0xuvW3sWWLCBOSnbd4TDRX_g) as a tool to select a number from a range with minimum value of 0. I am looking for a range picker view to be able to select a range of values (instead of a value from a range) including negative values (for example (-100, +200)).
Is there a pre-built solution for this?

Comment: NumberPicker has `void setMaxValue(int maxValue)` which *sets the max value of the picker* and `void setMinValue(int minValue)` which *sets the min value of the picker*. `Is there a pre-built solution for this?` Yes, it's called... **NumberPicker**.

Comment: @ModularSynth Yes, I've checked them. SetMinValue() does not allow you to set a value less than 0. However, there are some hacks out there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14357520/android-numberpicker-negative-numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no in-built solution for range picker, there are libraries out there which you can use to implement your requirement.
For example see this library : https://github.com/oli107/material-range-bar